# Do planar graphs have an acyclic two-coloring?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, planar-graphs

A graph has an *acyclic two-coloring* if its vertices can be colored with two colors such that each color class spans a forest.

> Does every planar graph have an acyclic two-coloring?

An affirmative answer would imply the four-color theorem, so I guess the answer has to be no, but I've failed to find a counterexample.
Or would this problem be equivalent to the four-color theorem?

Comment: The edges of any planar graph can be decomposed into $3$ forests, and this is tight ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arboricity ), but you aren't decomposing all the edges, and your forests are induced subgraphs.  Hmm...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

G. Chartrand, H.V. Kronk, C.E. Wall showed in "The point-arboricity of a graph" (Israel J. Math., 6 (1968), pp. 169–175) that the vertex-set of any planar graph can be partitioned into *three* induced forests.

Later, Chartrand and Kronk provided an example showing that 'three' cannot be replaced by 'two', see "THE POINT-ARBORICITY OF PLANAR GRAPHS" (J. London Math. Soc., 44 (1969), pp. 612–616). It is the dual of the *Tutte Graph*.

I think it is still an open problem whether every planar graph with $n$ vertices has an induced forest on $n/2$ vertices.

Comment: Now that I know the keyword, let me also link to http://www.math.illinois.edu/~dwest/regs/vertarb.html

Comment: Interestingly, the oriented version of the original question is still open. This version was conjectured by Neumann-Lara in 1985. See http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/partitioning_planar_digraphs

Answer (score 1):

Your question has already been answered by monkeymaths, but here is some more information.

The proof that every planar graph can be partitioned into *three* induced forests is actually quite easy.  Let $G$ be a planar graph and $v$ be a vertex of degree at most $5$.  By induction, $G-v$ can be partitioned into three induced forests.  Since $v$ has degree at most $5$, one of these forests $F$ contains at most one neighbour of $v$.  Thus, we can simply add $v$ to $F$.

Regarding the question of the largest induced forest of a planar graph (raised by monkeymaths), we can use the following theorem of Borodin.

**Theorem** (Borodin).  Every planar graph has an [acyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_coloring) $5$-colouring.

Here, an *acyclic colouring* is a proper colouring such that every $2$-coloured subgraph is acyclic (note that this is a different definition than in the original question, but is quite standard) .  By taking the two largest colour classes of an acyclic $5$-colouring, we get that every $n$-vertex planar graph has an induced forest with at least $\frac{2n}{5}$ vertices.  As far as I know, this is still the best lower bound. There are however improved bounds for triangle-free planar graphs.  For example,  [Dross, Montassier, and Pinlou](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1348) recently proved that every $n$-vertex triangle-free planar graph contains an induced forest with at least $\frac{6n+7}{11}$ vertices.